# Вывод массива с помощью рекурсии

Tags: c++, c, рекурсия

Необходимо вывести элементы массива в обратном порядке, при этом передать в функцию последний индекс массива. Что я делаю не так? Вот мой код :

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int Rev(int array[], int len) {
  if (len < 0) 
  {
return 0;
  } 
  else
  {
    array[len];
    Rev(array, len-1);
    cout << array[len] << "\n";
  }
}
int main() {
  int arr[6] = {42, 23, 16, 15, 8, 4};

  // вызов функции
Rev(arr, 5);

  return 0;
}
```

На выходе я получаю

```
42
23
16
15
8
4
```

т.е. в том же порядке, в котором элементы массива были заданы, а мне необходимо вывести их в обратном порядке.

Comment: Я подправил, там должно быть 5

Answer (score 2, accepted):

А зачем рекурсия? Почему бы не так:

```
void Rev(int array[], int len)
{
    for(int i = len; i >= 0; --i)
        cout << array[i] << "\n";
}

int main()
{
    int arr[6] = {42, 23, 16, 15, 8, 4};
    Rev(arr, 5);
}
```

А вы, если хотите рекурсивно - поменяйте местами строки

```
Rev(array, len-1);
cout << array[len] << "\n";
```

Comment: Спасибо. Стараюсь досконально разобраться с рекурсивными функциями, пока с переменным успехом.

Comment: Ну смотрите - вам надо вывести сначала последний элемент, а потом уже рекурсивно остальные. Вы же выводите остальные, а потом уже - последний. И так на каждом уровне рекурсии - в результате получается обычный порядок.

Answer (score 1):

для того, чтобы поменять порядок вам следовало бы как уже ответили выводить после рекурсивного вызова -

как альтернативный вариант можно воспользоваться прекрасным свойством статических переменных которые сохраняют свои старые значения между вызовами (заодно и это подучите)

```
    void Rev(int array[], int len) 
    {
        static int i = 0;
        if (i < len)
        {
            cout << array[len-i-1] << ' '; ++i;
            Rev(array, len);
        }
    }
```

Comment: А при следующем вызове для другого массива не будет ли мешать сохраненное в `i` значение?

Comment: @Mikhailo да вы правы - для следующего массива ничего не выведется так как переменная `i` будет иметь значение `len`